# ie10, ie11 issue with skewX (double use causes rendering issues)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I can't seem to figure these bugs out (I've gone through the normal bug checking processes - validation, console debugging, etc..).

Somehow, the site is working properly on most recent browsers (latest 3 versions on both windows and mac of safari, chrome, firefox, opera) and it works on ie9, but ie10 and ie11 have some major bugs (my testing is happening on browserstack).

Site in questions on test server: http://flourishcle.com/globalmba/

ie10//ie11 issues:

- The `.content` within each `#semester` disappears - I see it on slide-in and then it vanishes
- `min-width` on the imgs within `.content` has unwanted results (even with `height: auto` applied)
- `Overflow: hidden` is not being respected (in associated with the skewed pseudo elements) - the overlapping content blocks clicking of underlying content

My first thought was an issue with the `display: table` I use to create the structure of the site, but that shouldn't be affecting visuals or creating squished images.

---

**EDIT // UPDATE**

So, I've narrowed the problem to a specific issue with SkewX and ie10/ie11.

Basic HTML:

```
<section class="section-1 angled">
  <div class="wrapper">
    //Content
  </div>
</section>
//Structure repeated multiple times
```

Basic CSS (Using Compass to import vendor specifics):

```
.angled {
  -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}

.wrapper {
  -moz-transform: skewX(20deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
  transform: skewX(20deg);
}
```

If I disable either one of the skewX styles everything works as expected (except it looks skewed in a bad way).

When both are enabled, however, there are text issues: the text, divs, etc. just stop being visible. If you open up dev tools and select the div sometimes the content will show up. If you select the area where the text should be sometimes it will show up. But generally the content just doesn't show up. I haven't seen this as a reported bug. I know there are workarounds for targeting ie > 9 (since conditional comments aren't supported, but hoping to find a solution).

*Skew problems don't seem to affect ie9

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because you're missing closing brackets. I tried looking at screen.css but the formatting is so bad that I can't easily tell.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok - I thought it might be the CSS too, but I went through the SASS files. It's condensed compiled sass, that might be why it looks messy.

Comment: Is it possible that browserstack is just not showing the content? The content appears to be there, but just isn't showing up. Even when I disable all the opacity settings, it doesn't show up in browserstack. I haven't been able to get my hands on a windows enabled device yet.

Comment: "Is it possible that browserstack is just not showing the content?" No. I tested in IE 11. It's definitely not there.

Comment: The unusual thing is that I can get the content to show up. Let's say that you clicked on 1st semester. The content transition appears and then disappears. If I open up the developer console and hover over #semester-one the content reappears.

Comment: Honestly, your website needs some severe help. You have so many problems that stackoverflow won't be able to help you. If you could break the problems down to just the relevant code and post them as separate problems you'll have much better luck.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok Sorry, didn't see earlier comments - yeah. But why would content appear/disappear on highlight? In testing, I've gone back and turned off most insignificant styling - still having issues. Could it be the skew is causing the problems? That's really the only problem I'm having - everything else works as expected. And certainly works on all other browsers as expected. What other issues are you seeing, I'd like to address those too. Be happy to take into a chat if you're willing

Comment: Alright, so it's definitely the skew that causes the issues. After disabling all skewing, there are no issues at all, and all rendering/functionality happens as expected for all browsers. Just need to find an alternate to skew for ie10/11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know if you are still looking for a solution, but i found a "fix" for ie10 and ie11.

Replace the child div style by :

```
.wrapper {
  -moz-transform: skewX(20.01deg);
  -ms-transform: skewX(20.01deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20.01deg);
  transform: skewX(20.01deg);
}
```

Looks like ie have issue rendering the double skew when values are the same. (Didn't dig it up to see why, yet) 
I tried changing them, and having two different values seems to do the trick.

The + .01deg allows you to keep a skew almost identical (if not identical) to the 20deg skew from before.

Answer (score -1):

**@jack [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157861/ie10-ie11-issue-with-skewx-double-use-causes-rendering-issues#answer-34394574) is correct!**

Relying on that IE do not consume inverted angles of same value, you can add 
 `-360` degrees to your skew value and apply to the inner element.

```
.angled {
    -moz-transform: skewX(-380deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-380deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-380deg);
    transform: skewX(-380deg);
}

.wrapper {
    -moz-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
    transform: skewX(20deg);
}
```